# Remove 'Target Path' Column

Tags: 2013, column, required

I have a colleague that created a list that I inherited.  It was created as a task list, and comes complete with the column 'Target Path', which is not only a required field, but I cannot seem to delete it.
How do I get rid of this annoyance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain columns in SharePoint which we cannot delete from a list setting page or UI once it is added to the list. The **Target Path** column is one among them, see the below list of columns which we cannot delete from the UI.

These columns we can delete only using the **PowerShell script** (script is given below).

- Active
- Aliases
- Article Date
- Byline
- Contact
- Contact E-Mail Address
- Contact Name
- Contact Picture
- Custom Router
- Image Caption
- Page Content
- Page Icon
- Page Image
- Priority
- Properties used in Conditions
- Property for Automatic Folder Creation
- Rollup Image
- Route To External Location
- Rule Name
- Scheduling End Date
- Scheduling Start Date
- Submission Content Type
- Summary Links
- Summary Links 2
- Target Audiences
- Target Folder
- Target Library
- **Target Path**

In the above list **Target Path** column is also listed.

We can delete the above columns using the PowerShell script. Here is the script we can use that.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb (Your site URL)
$list = $web.Lists[(Your List Name)]
$field = $list.Fields[(Your Column Name)]
$field.AllowDeletion = “true”
$field.Sealed = “false”
$field.Delete()
$list.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

For details refer to the below article :

["I cannot delete this column from my list??" - Well that must be a SharePoint 2010 Peristent column](http://huzefamala.blogspot.com/2012/05/i-cannot-delete-this-column-from-my.html?m=1)

Comment: Hi @DanJ - Did your issue get resolved? Could you please update.